# Mapping KeyValuePair's from different IEnumerable's

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, lambda

The problem:

I need to match the data from my `reducedList` matching it with my `coreList`, some kind of join, where the key("Year, Id, House...") of `reducedList` will be matched against my `coreList`'s key (list) and those 2 results will be merged into temporary result list `tempList`- this will be one column.

The final goal is to use my later merged data to fill an entire excel column, where the first entry in `tempList` is the heading and the rest is the data.

The source code is commented out, hopefully it helps.

At first my example works, but I need a better approach and maybe more performant or a different way to solve the problem, I think I need a better mapping approach/algorithm.

That's  my approach:

Core data(everything):

```
Dictionary<String, Object> coreList = (Dictionary<String, Object>)_rawCoreList
    .Where(x => x.Key.Equals("ListOfCities"))
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);//filter the property out I need
```

Init data( this list will be matched later against the `coreList`):

```
List<KeyValuePair<String, String>> reducedList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

reducedList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Id", "1. Heading"));
reducedList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Year", "2. Heading"));
reducedList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("House", "3. Heading"));
reducedList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Garage", "4. Heading"));
reducedList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Basdlf", "The key does not exist"));
//reducedList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(null, null));//check for strange data
```

Combining/matching property names from the reduced list(only a few properties) with the core list(all properties):

```
List<KeyValuePair<String/* Property-Name */, object /* Werte Property-Name */>> ergebnisListe = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();//"" daraus ein Array machen

#region Matching with the reduced list

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, String> reducedListItem in reducedList)
{
    List<string> tempList = new List<string>();

    tempList.Add(reducedListItem.Value != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(reducedListItem.Value) ? reducedListItem.Value : "!Überschrift_FEHLER!");//adding the heading first

    #region Itereating through the core list, to get the rest for my data set(actually I need some mapping)

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Object> item in coreList)
    {
        #region Filter for my desired list

        if (item.Value is IEnumerable && item.Value.GetType().IsGenericType) //matching only for lists, I expect to work with
        {
            foreach (Dictionary<string, object> subItemListItem in item.Value as List<object>)// I am exspecting some kind of list with "KeyValuePair"'s
            {
                if (subItemListItem.ContainsKey(reducedListItem.Key))//checking for valid keys
                {
                    //doing something with "subItemListItem.Values" or "Keys" ?!
                    tempList.Add(subItemListItem[reducedListItem.Key] != null ? subItemListItem[reducedListItem.Key].ToString() : "ERROR");
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion

    }

    #endregion

    #region Adding the result to my final list

    // adding one column/record
    ergebnisListe.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(reducedListItem.Key, tempList.ToArray())); //I need "string[]" first record is the heading and the rest is it's related data

    #endregion
}
```

I am almost free to change the data structure and types  except for the core list.

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a LINQ version:

```
// Getting dictionaries from coreList
var dictsInCoreList =
    coreList
        .Values
        .Where(value => value is IEnumerable && value.GetType().IsGenericType)
        .SelectMany(value => value as List<object>)
        .Cast<Dictionary<string, object>>()
        .ToList();

// Generate the result
ergebnisListe =
    reducedList
        .Select(reducedListItem =>
            {
                var tempList =
                    new List<string>()
                    {
                        String.IsNullOrEmpty(reducedListItem.Value)
                            ? "!Überschrift_FEHLER"
                            : reducedListItem.Value
                    };

                tempList.AddRange(
                    dictsInCoreList
                        .Where(dict => dict.ContainsKey(reducedListItem.Key))
                        .Select(dict => dict[reducedListItem.Key]?.ToString() ?? "ERROR")
                );

                return new KeyValuePair<string, object>(reducedListItem.Key, tempList);
            }
        )
        .ToList();
```

This is something faster due to collection of all dictionaries in the first statement.

However I think that something needs to be refactored because if `coreList` contained only lists (so that we would not need to filter the type of the `.Value` property) then the real type of it would be `Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, object>>>` which smells a bit for me.

But without more domain knowledge of your solution currently I cannot suggest a better mapping.